Killing form that is not diagonalizable?
An example Lie algebra $L$ with non-diagonalizable Killing form would have to be non-semisimple, and the Killing form complex. (Otherwise diagonalizability is obvious.) I tried with a few $L$, but (in a proper base) the result always was of the type $diag(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,1)$ however I chose $L$. Do you have an example $L$ or a proof of diagonalizability?

Isn't every complex quadratic form diagonalizable?

The Killing form is a complex quadratic-form and therefore given by complex symmetric (note - not Hermitian!) matrix (with respect to some basis).
\begin{align}
    B(x,y) = x^T A y,
\end{align}
complex symmetric matrices may be diagonalised by a unitary and it's transpose (note - not conjugate-transpose!). I.e. for any complex symmetric $A$ there exists a unitary $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$, with real, non-negative entries such that
\begin{align}
D = U A U^T.
\end{align}
This is known as the Autonne–Takagi factorization (although it was also discovered by Hua and others).
I would like to emphasise that this is not the usual spectral theorem that applies to normal matrices as complex symmetric matrices do not have to be normal.

Does this mean that if my Killing form is A, I can choose the basis of the Lie algebra so that it is D? (Since this isn't the "usual" diagonalization.)

@HaukeReddmann yes - this diagonalization is exactly what you want in this case because your form is given by $x^T A y$, and not $x^\dagger A y$.
